# fetch multiple records from a single table having same id

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am writing a function in laravel 5.8 in which I want to get sum of the user amount that lies within my selected range, I am using the two input fields in view which they get the price range "T0 and From" e.g if the user enters 100 and 1000, it should show the list of the users who has amount > 100 and amount < 1000. The problem is there are multiple records of the same users as shown below in the table.
I want to sum the amount of the users and show the user if their amount is within range

table name= deposits

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>user_id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>ali</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>ali</td>
<td>800</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>ali</td>
<td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>khan</td>
<td>1100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>james</td>
<td>850</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>james</td>
<td>90</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior of your query is correct, to get what you need it is necessary to work on the query.
Assuming this fields in your `deposits` table: `id, user_id, name, amount` in according with data showing in the table.

You need to sum the `amount` grouping by `user_id`

Example query:

```
$deposit = Deposits::select(
                       'id',
                       'user_id',
                       'name',
                       'sum(amount)',
                    )->whereBetween('amount', [100, 1000])
                    ->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "sum(amount)" does not exist LINE 1: select "id", "user_id", "name", "sum(amount)" from "deposits"... You need use 'DB::raw('sum(amount)' instead of 'sum(amount'. But, you will have another error "column "id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". So u need exclude id and name from select function

Comment: Why i need to exclude name from select function? when i grouping the name is the same because user_id refers in a unique way to the user...but in the sum(amount) i've missed the DB::raw() as you rightly pointed out to me

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('deposits')
        ->selectRaw('user_id, SUM(amount) as total_amount')
        ->where('amount', '>', '100')
        ->where('amount', '<', '1000')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->get();
```

Result is:

```
[
  {
    "user_id":9,
    "total_amount":850
  },
  {
    "user_id":12,
    "total_amount":800
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app('db')
   ->table('users')
   ->select('name')
   ->selectRaw("SUM(amount) as total_amounts")
   ->havingBetween('total_amounts', [ 100, 1000 ])
   ->groupBy('user_id')
   ->get();
```

You can use the raw query for the sum per user and use the having between for the sum of amounts.